# ¿Como configurar "npm install" automatico en elastic beanstalk?

Tags: nodejs, aws

Hola tengo una instancia nodejs en elastic beanstalk y cuando subo mi proyecto con `eb deploy` tengo que entrar a mi instancia mediante ssh y adentro ejecutar el comando `npm install`

¿Como puedo automatizar el proceso?

¿Se configura en este archivo?

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: nodeproyects-dev
environment-defaults:
nodeproyects-dev:
  branch: null
  repository: null
global:
  application_name: nodeproyects
  default_ec2_keyname: NodeConection
  default_platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-2::platform/Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux/4.0.1
  default_region: us-west-2
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

De ser así ¿en parte y como lo debo configurar?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

No tengo claro de qué fichero estás hablando.

En cualquier caso, la manera adecuada de hacerlo es mediante archivos de configuración en formato **YAML** dentro de la carpeta **.ebextensions**. Dicha carpeta debe estar en la raíz de tu empaquetado web sobre el que hayas hecho deploy.

Entre las funcionalidades (nativas) más comunes tienes:

- Personalizar propiedades del stack de tu entorno.
- Instalar paquetes adicionales.
- Crear usuarios en la nueva instancia EC2.
- Descarga y creación de ficheros de ficheros.
- Y por supuesto, ejecutar cualquier conjunto de comandos a tu elección.

La configuración es bastante amplia y flexible, échale un vistazo a la documentación oficial de **.ebextensions** [aquí](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html).